# VLC does not show when opening media files

Tags: vlc-media-player, file-association

Previously VLC opened with all video media just by clicking on the video media file. Recently I then played a couple of audio playlists by the the 'add media interface ribbon' i.e loading multiple tracks, now if I click on a video media  file the program will not open automatically or if I right click the video media file and select 'play with' the program will not open

Comment: Does rebooting your computer resolve the issue? Alternatively you may open Task Manager and kill the VLC application.

Comment: Thank you Mokubai. opening Task manager and cancelling VLC exe has indeed solved the problem..... I would ask a further question if I may, do you know what could be the cause??

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the program may have gotten confused and it is stuck "closing down" while you are trying to open new items with it.  It is difficult to know how it got into this state and often the only way to clear it is to force the program to close. Most programs are difficult to get into this state, but programming errors can occur.

You may be able to open the Task Manager (using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> amongst others) and find the `VLC` or `vlc.exe` item and closing it.

Alternatively the brute force and ignorance method would be to reboot your computer.

If this happens regularly then you should contact the makers of VLC and mention the steps required to get it into this state as it is most certainly a programming error of some kind.